# Bluetoothconnection error

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, connection

I'm kinda new to the android programming, but now I wanted to try to program an App that connects my phone(samsung galaxy note 2) with a circuit board over bluetooth. I just want to power on/off some LED's. I'm using a bc417 modem on the circuit board.

I already searched for bluetooth examples, but they all seem to be so difficult and i just want the commands I need. But at the moment my app crashes all the time when I select an Item on the ListView.

Can anybody help me please?

```
package com.test.bluetoothtest;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
private static final UUID myuuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if(mBluetoothAdapter == null)
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Bluetooth couldn't be started.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
    {
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Bluetooth started succesfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    List<String> devicelist = new ArrayList<String>();

    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    if(pairedDevices.size() > 0)
    {
        for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices)
        {
            devicelist.add(device.getName());

        }
    }
    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, devicelist);
    final ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, lv.getAdapter().getItem(arg2).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                BluetoothDevice finaldevice = (BluetoothDevice) lv.getAdapter().getItem(arg2);                  
                BluetoothSocket clientSocket = finaldevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(myuuid);
                clientSocket.connect();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Connectin successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Catlog :

```
07-10 20:38:55.115: D/AbsListView(16942): Get MotionRecognitionManager
07-10 20:38:55.335: D/libEGL(16942): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
07-10 20:38:55.345: D/libEGL(16942): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
07-10 20:38:55.345: D/libEGL(16942): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
07-10 20:38:55.350: D/(16942): Device driver API match
07-10 20:38:55.350: D/(16942): Device driver API version: 10
07-10 20:38:55.350: D/(16942): User space API version: 10 
07-10 20:38:55.350: D/(16942): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Tue Oct 16 15:37:13 KST 2012 
07-10 20:38:55.400: D/OpenGLRenderer(16942): Enabling debug mode 0
07-10 20:39:05.145: D/GestureDetector(17303): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 2 mFalseSizeCnt:0
07-10 20:39:05.240: D/AndroidRuntime(17303): Shutting down VM
07-10 20:39:05.240: W/dalvikvm(17303): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40db82a0)
07-10 20:39:05.245: E/AndroidRuntime(17303): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-10 20:39:05.245: E/AndroidRuntime(17303): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice
07-10 20:39:05.245: E/AndroidRuntime(17303):    at com.test.bluetoothtest.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:74)
07-10 20:39:05.245: E/AndroidRuntime(17303):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
07-10 20:39:05.245: E/AndroidRuntime(17303):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1283)
07-10 20:39:05.245: E/AndroidRuntime(17303):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3074)
07-10 20:39:05.245: E/AndroidRuntime(17303):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:4147)
07-10 20:39:05.245: E/AndroidRuntime(17303):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-10 20:39:05.245: E/AndroidRuntime(17303):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-10 20:39:05.245: E/AndroidRuntime(17303):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-10 20:39:05.245: E/AndroidRuntime(17303):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
07-10 20:39:05.245: E/AndroidRuntime(17303):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-10 20:39:05.245: E/AndroidRuntime(17303):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-10 20:39:05.245: E/AndroidRuntime(17303):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
07-10 20:39:05.245: E/AndroidRuntime(17303):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
07-10 20:39:05.245: E/AndroidRuntime(17303):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-10 20:41:33.045: D/AbsListView(18494): Get MotionRecognitionManager
07-10 20:41:33.155: D/libEGL(18494): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
07-10 20:41:33.160: D/libEGL(18494): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
07-10 20:41:33.165: D/libEGL(18494): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
07-10 20:41:33.170: D/(18494): Device driver API match
07-10 20:41:33.170: D/(18494): Device driver API version: 10
07-10 20:41:33.170: D/(18494): User space API version: 10 
07-10 20:41:33.170: D/(18494): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Tue Oct 16 15:37:13 KST 2012 
07-10 20:41:33.225: D/OpenGLRenderer(18494): Enabling debug mode 0
07-10 20:41:34.975: D/GestureDetector(18494): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 3 mFalseSizeCnt:0
07-10 20:41:35.110: D/AndroidRuntime(18494): Shutting down VM
07-10 20:41:35.110: W/dalvikvm(18494): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40db82a0)
07-10 20:41:35.115: E/AndroidRuntime(18494): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-10 20:41:35.115: E/AndroidRuntime(18494): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice
07-10 20:41:35.115: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at com.test.bluetoothtest.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:75)
07-10 20:41:35.115: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
07-10 20:41:35.115: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1283)
07-10 20:41:35.115: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3074)
07-10 20:41:35.115: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:4147)
07-10 20:41:35.115: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-10 20:41:35.115: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-10 20:41:35.115: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-10 20:41:35.115: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
07-10 20:41:35.115: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-10 20:41:35.115: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-10 20:41:35.115: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
07-10 20:41:35.115: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
07-10 20:41:35.115: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-10 20:41:47.780: I/Process(18494): Sending signal. PID: 18494 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I know you are new, but try to keep in mind that some research on your part goes a *long way* to helping you out. What was the error you were getting? Please show your efforts first so that other people might help you out. Also, please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the following line

```
BluetoothDevice finaldevice = (BluetoothDevice) lv.getAdapter().getItem(arg2);
```

getItem returns String not a BluetoothDevice. Your cast fails.

Do the following.

You query for the paired devices and display them in the listview. From a paired device, you need its Mac Address in order to create connection. When you are iterating through the paired devices, you can extract each one's address. Later in your on click do the following to get a BluetoothDevice.

```
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
// If there are paired devices
if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
    // Loop through paired devices
    for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
        // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
        mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
    }
}
```

Later extract this address when an item is clicked from Item's text and use it accordingly.

```
BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
```

Then get BluetoothSocket with the following

```
 btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
```

Then you can use this socket to connect.

```
btSocket.connect();
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. But how do I get the BluetoothDevice then?

Answer (score 0):

it would be nice to know where your App crashes. And LogCat also could be helpfull.
Since I had some Problems with UUID myself I'm working with

```
Method m = finaldevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[]{int.class});
clientSocket = (Bluetoothsocket) m.invoke(finaldevice, Integer.valueOf(1));
clientSocket.connect();
```

It works for me.

Comment: eclipse told me to put some catch clauses around ur code, but it still doesn't work :(, my app crashes if i click on an item in the listview, means somewhere there at the public void onItemClick function